# How to find the adjoint of a linear transformation between Hilbert spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $T:H \to H$ be a bounded linear transformation between Hilbert spaces. How to construct its adjoint and how to prove that its adjoint is unique?

I know that $\langle Tx,y\rangle =\langle x,T^* y\rangle $ and I am wondering how to find the adjoint of a linear transformation in general.

Answer (score 2):

for a fixed $y\in H$ the map :
$$
\phi_y : H \to \mathbb{C} 
$$
defined by :
$$
\phi_y(x)=\langle Tx, y\rangle 
$$
is a  continuous linear functionals, in fact 
$$
|\phi_y(x)|=|\langle Tx, y\rangle |\leq \|Tx\|\|y\|\leq \|T\|\|y\|\|x\|
$$
by [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) we can get a unique $Y\in H$ such that :
$$
\phi_y(x)=\langle x, Y \rangle
$$
the maps who match every $y$ to $Y$ is denoted by $T^*$, and verify :
$$
\langle Tx, y\rangle =\langle x , T^* y\rangle
$$